# How to apply button properties to css

Tags: c++

My question will be about c programming

I created my c program 
and **it includes ;**

There are values which is entered by keyboard between M between N value.

**And question is ;**
Calculate How many times the smallest value repeated which is entered by keyboard.

My example codes are

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() {
    long say[k], ek;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. sayiyi girin:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &say[k]);
    }

    ek=x[0];
    for (i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        if (x[i]<ek)ek=x[i];
    }

    printf("en kücük sayi:%ld\n", ek);
    return1;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;

    printf("ilk sayiyi girin:");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("ikinci sayiyi girin:");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    printf("iki sayi arasinda kac tane sayi yazilacagini gir:");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    {
        printf("en cok tekrar edilen:");
        for (i=0, i<k, i++)
        {
            if (eleman[i]==0) break;
            {
                printf("%d", eleman[i]);
            }
            printf("en kücük:%d", ek);
        }
        getch();
        return0;
    }
}
```

what is wrong on it ?

filter: dropshadow(color=#bababa, offx=0, offy=0); }

Comment: Huh? What is your question?

Comment: What's wrong? Does it compile? Does it run correctly? What does it do that is wrong?

Comment: First problem: You have two `main` functions--only one is allowed.

Comment: What does this have to do with buttons or CSS (HTML style sheets)?  There is no reference to a button or HTML.

Comment: Multiple problems here: "*My question will be about c programming 
I created my c program and it includes ;*" Why are you tagging this as C++? Second the title has nothing to do with the question. Extrange error

Answer (score 1):

**In your first `main` function:**

You use an array `x` without declaring it.

You are using `scanf` function which is evil.  Use `std::cin` since you tagged this as C++.

The variable or limit of the `for` loop, `k`, is never initialized.

**In the second `main` function:**

The array `eleman` is not declared nor initialized.

You have a statement group declared after the `if` statement, don't know if this is intentional:

```
if (eleman[i]==0)
    break;
{ // Is this part of the "if" statement?
    printf("%d", eleman[i]);
}
printf("en kücük:%d", ek);
```

You are using `<conio>` which means you are using an old compiler.
Try this:

```
std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue.\n";
std::cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
```

For code reviews, please post on CodeReview.StackExchange.com